# enum define in template class in c++

Tags: c++, templates, enums

My code describes two classes that implement simple enum defined in `class "a"` and function `"getNum`" that uses the `enum` and i get the following comilation errors:

1."`C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Etry`
2."`C4346: 'a<T>::Etry': dependent name is not a type`

The code:

> a class:

```
template <typename T>
class a

{

public:

enum Etry
{
    AAA,
    BBB,
    CCC
};

a()
{
    printf("\nconstructor of a class.\n");
};

};
```

> b class:

```
template <typename T>
class b
{
public:

    void getNum(int num, a<T>::Etry enumParam)
    {
        printf("\nbla bla....\n");
    }

    b() {
        printf("\nconstructor of b class.\n");
    }
};
```

Why did I get the errors?

Comment: Did you already try using `typename a<T>::Etry enumParam`?

Comment: Yeah you just need to put `typename` before your argument. See the link in the comment above for why.